# SQL query to select values from a table where the condition is from related tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm struggling to write a SELECT query in my PHP application. The situation is following:

I have table ADDRESS with one-to-many relation to table CONTEST. The relation is via junction table ContestHasAddress. CONTEST table has many-to-many relation to DATE table via junction table ContestHasDate.

I was trying to SELECT all columns from ADDRESS table WHERE the column1 from DATE related to its CONTEST (who is related to the ADDRESS) is bigger then a specific VALUE. I have attached the linke below showing the relation view from phpmyadmin.

I tried that but it was a failure

```
SELECT address.*
FROM address,
     contest,
     date
WHERE address.contest.dates[0].start_time > TIMESTAMPVALUE
```

[image: Link showing the table design]

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: How are "*relations*" coded in SQL? Do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `JOIN`s to establish all of the table relations to get to the `Date` table.  Then, you can compare the values:

```
Select  A.*
From    Address                 A
Join    Contest_Has_Address     CA  On  A.Id = CA.Address_Id
Join    Contest                 C   On  C.Id = CA.Contest_Id
Join    Contest_Has_Date        CD  On  C.Id = CD.Contest_Id
Join    Date                    D   On  D.Id = CD.Date_Id
Where   D.Start_Time > TIMESTAMPVALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables using the "junction table". I have assumed that Startime is DateTime field and not Int.

```
Select address.* from Address inner join ContestHasAddress 
on Address.ID = Contest_Has_Address.address_ID INNER JOIN
Contest_Has_Date on Contest_Has_Address.ContestID = Contest_Has_Date.contestID
inner join date on Contest_Has_Date.DateId = Date.ID
where StartTime > TIMESTAMPVALUE
```